# How to reshape DataFrame for nested JSON output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am starting to work with some data manipulation and I need to create a new file (with new features) out of an old one. However, I could not realize how can I customize my own dataframe before using a ".to_json" method.

For example, I have a .csv as:

```
seller, customer, product, price
Roger, Will, 8129, 30
Roger, Markus, 1234, 100
Roger, Will, 2334, 50
Mike, Markus, 2295, 20
Mike, Albert, 1234, 100
```

...and I want to generate a .json file to support me in visualizing a network out of it. This should be more or less like:

```
{
"node": [
      {"id":"Roger", "group": "seller" },
      {"id":"Mike", "group": "seller" },
      {"id":"Will", "group": "customer" },
      {"id":"Markus", "group": "customer" },
      {"id":"Albert", "group": "customer" }
],
"links":[
      {"source":"Roger","target":"Will","product":8129,"price":30},
      #...and so on
]
}
```

I tried to do something like:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
seller_list = df1.seller.unique()
customer_list = df1.customer.unique()
```

..and I could get indeed lists with unique items. However, I could not find how I should add them in a dataframe in order to create an structure such as:

```
"node":[
      ...
      {"id":"Mike", "group": "seller" },
      {"id":"Markus", "group": "customer" },
      ...
]...#see above
```

Any support or hint on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a two step process. First, create the `nodes` dict using `melt` + `drop_duplicates` +`to_dict` -

```
nodes = df[['customer', 'seller']]\
           .melt(var_name='group', value_name='id')\
           .drop_duplicates()\
           .to_dict('r')
```

Now, create the `links` dict using `rename` + `to_dict`

```
links = df.rename(columns={'seller' : 'source', 'customer' : 'target'}).to_dict('r')
```

Now, combine the data into one dictionary, and dump it as JSON to a file.

```
data = {'nodes' : nodes, 'links' : links}

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Your `data.json` file should look like this -

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "Will",
            "group": "customer"
        },
        {
            "id": "Markus",
            "group": "customer"
        },
        {
            "id": "Albert",
            "group": "customer"
        },
        {
            "id": "Roger",
            "group": "seller"
        },
        {
            "id": "Mike",
            "group": "seller"
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "product": 8129,
            "target": "Will",
            "source": "Roger",
            "price": 30
        },
        {
            "product": 1234,
            "target": "Markus",
            "source": "Roger",
            "price": 100
        },
        {
            "product": 2334,
            "target": "Will",
            "source": "Roger",
            "price": 50
        },
        {
            "product": 2295,
            "target": "Markus",
            "source": "Mike",
            "price": 20
        },
        {
            "product": 1234,
            "target": "Albert",
            "source": "Mike",
            "price": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello COLDSPEED, your answer looks great! Thanks a lot!! I would have another tiny question for you, if possible. What if I want to exclude one of the dimensions from the "links" half. For example, exclude "product" and leave just "target", "source", and "price". What method can I use in order to reduce this dimensionality?

Comment: @RogerAlmeidaLeite before computing links, do: df = df.drop("product",1)